# Error Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error while installing STAMP

Tags: installation, version, setup.py, stamp

I am trying to install (linux) STAMP so I can analyze my PICRUST output. The code I'm following is:

sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran
sudo apt-get install freetype* python-pip python-dev python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
sudo pip install STAMP

The error I get is:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[1 lines of output\]
Only Python 2.7 and 3.3 are supported.
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I created a conda environment with python 2.7 and another one with python 3.3 but in both of them I keep getting the same error. Any ideas on how I could install STAMP?